# Populate datagrid with items based on a name vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a code that basically gets me the index of a hidden combobox I then use that index to populate a datagrid, however I only want to show the items which correspond to the text in the lbl_test.text label.

```
Private Sub CBX_Doctors_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CBX_Doctors.SelectedIndexChanged
    lbl_test.Text = CBX_Doctors.SelectedItem.ToString
    CBX_hidden.SelectedItem = lbl_test.Text
    lbl_hidden.Text = CBX_hidden.SelectedIndex.ToString

    Dim app = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_hidden.Text)
    DGV_1.DataSource = AppointmentList
End Sub



Public Class Appointment

   Property AppointmentID As String
   Property AppointmentDate As String
   Property Time As String
   Property AppointmentLength As Integer
   Property DoctorName As String
   Property PatientName As String
   Property Reason As String

End Class
```

This was a requested portion of the code responsible for saving to an xml file:

```
 'save to the xml
    Dim objStreamWriter4 As New StreamWriter("..\..\..\Appointments.xml")
    Dim a As New XmlSerializer(AppointmentList.GetType)
    a.Serialize(objStreamWriter4, AppointmentList)
    objStreamWriter4.Close()
```

Comment: What is `AppointmentList`?

Comment: @OneFineDay Public AppointmentList As New List(Of Appointment)

Comment: Could you show the class and it's members.

Comment: Sure, I edited the original post to show the class.

Comment: Which field does it correlate to?

Comment: I am trying to search for doctor name in the xml created and return all appointments related to that doctor to the datagrid.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to filter the return list based on one of the fields equals the `lbl_test.Text` - if that is correct then you could do something like:

```
Private Sub CBX_Doctors_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CBX_Doctors.SelectedIndexChanged
   Dim doctorName = CBX_Doctors.SelectedItem.ToString
   CBX_hidden.SelectedItem = doctorName
   lbl_hidden.Text = CBX_hidden.SelectedIndex.ToString
   DGV_1.DataSource = AppointmentList.Where(Function(apt) apt.DoctorName = doctorName)
End Sub
```

Comment: I wrote:  DGV_1.DataSource = AppointmentList.Where(Function(apt) apt.DoctorName = lbl_test.Text)   But the datagrid stays blank when I do the change on the combobox?

Comment: Does the selectedItem match the doctor names from the `AppointmentList`?

Comment: Does the `AppointmentList` data persist between these changes?

Comment: The answer to all is yes, the <DoctorName>Dana Scully</DoctorName> and the name in lbl_test.text would be Dana Scully so it should work.

Comment: I agree, so try some debugging and check the values.

Comment: I just tried, the label shows a name but the apt.DoctorName seems empty it shows no value.

Comment: How are you filling `AppointmentList`? Serialization from `XML`?